# SCRUM certification in UK, for Australia?

Tags: certification

I have the week off and would like to get certified as a scrum master. I have run small projects but want official certification. I have recently been employed at a new employer who wants me to run a couple of small projects, and I want to do a great job.

https://www.careermatch-uk.com/management-courses/certified-scrum-master-csm.html#product_tabs_course_outline

I found this. Does anyone know if this is worth doing and would it be recognised as certification in Australia? There seems to be coupons to get thiss quite cheap.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so having been in slightly a similar situation, I would advise you go for [PSM I](https://www.scrum.org/professional-scrum-certifications/professional-scrum-master-assessments) and if you are up for it, maybe even PSM II or one of the other certifications offered by [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/professional-scrum-certifications).

These are all issued by Scrum.org, an organization founded by Ken Schwaber, who is scrum's co-author.

I passed PSM I by simply reading the Scrum Guide, which is like 16 pages document. For PSM II, I pulled some of my old books and just freshened my memory on the parts that you don't tend to use at work. Do not aim for PSM II without having an excellent knowledge of Nexus or scaled scrum, something I knew about beforehand..

The exams aren't trivial but if you have some experience with Scrum and prepare well, you should pass it.

All Scrum.org certifications are recognized globally, are cheaper than all the other similar certifications and do not require that you attend an expensive course.

A side note: certifications help your CV get noticed but do not guarantee a job. You will still need to be experienced enough to answer non-theory questions.

Comment: Indeed. Getting a certificate like PSM I is probably the easiest part of becoming a Scrum Master. I did a weeklong prep course for it and it was way more useful in terms of additional knowledge than in terms of preparing for the exam.